# Playing video on Blackberry devices using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, cordova

I am developing an application for Blackberry devices using Phonegap. I need to play a video in my application. Is it possible to play video using Javascript? If yes please tell how it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting BB6 and up, you can use an HTML5 video player. My favorite library is [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) but [here is a full list](http://html5video.org/wiki/Property%3aBlackberry) of compatible libraries.